# Update table with constant value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 7 columns (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6) in my table and I want to exectute the following query:

```
UPDATE myTable SET s0=ROUND(s0/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100,
  s1=ROUND(s1/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100, 
  s2=ROUND(s2/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100,
  s3=ROUND(s3/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100, 
  s4=ROUND(s4/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100, 
  s5=ROUND(s5/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100, 
  s6=ROUND(s6/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100;
```

The problem is that mysql updates `s1` and then calculates `s2`, etc.

How can I fix for each row the value `(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)` in the sql request ?

Comment: I like MySQL, but this is one of the reasons it makes me sad... :-/

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Is that behavior MySQL-specific? I was surprised to see this question, I use mostly MS SQL and I think this update would work fine there, wouldn't it?

Comment: Sounds like someone did a terribad job designing this table.

Comment: @peter.petrov It's MySQL specific... ["This behavior differs from standard SQL"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it should do the job as well (assuming table has a primary key):

```
UPDATE myTable a
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT ROUND(s0/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100 AS new_s0,
  ROUND(s1/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100 AS new_s1, 
  ROUND(s2/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100 AS new_s2,
  ROUND(s3/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100 AS new_s3, 
  ROUND(s4/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100 AS new_s4, 
  ROUND(s5/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100 AS new_s5, 
  ROUND(s6/(s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6)*100)/100 AS new_s6,
  pk_column 
  FROM myTable
)b ON (b.pk_column = a.pk_column)
SET a.s0 = b.new_s0, ....
```

Comment: I think this one is best provided the table has a PK (and it should have one anyway).

Comment: You should remove the s1=, s2= and so on, I think. I mean in the sub-query.

Comment: @peter.petrov : thank you, stupid mistake - I just copied from the question. Fixing

Answer (score 2):

An obvious solution is:

Add column sum to your table.
Update the sum (populate it with value for each row, this is trivial).
Then use the sum column in your query (instead of s0+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6).
Finally drop the sum column.

Comment: @PaulFournel Well, not the best if you have lots of lots of rows though. Also I don't like that I modify the table structure. But you can use temp table too. It all depends on how much data you have. I didn't quite get the other solution with the variables but if it works, it would seem better than mine btw.

Comment: @TMcKeown And yours doesn't seem like a solution at all. The one from a1ex07 is best, I think.

Comment: lol, mine is how people who write stored procedures would update a row.  If you can't see that then I doubt the professionalism of your projects.

Comment: @TMcKeown :) No, seriously, what if this table has 10 rows. How do you do it? Maybe I am missing something obvious here or you thought the table has just 1 row. These s0, s1 and so on, they are columns, not rows.

Comment: the question posed was updating a single row.  If the question was how do I handle set operations for that update then the UPDATE would be different, most likely performing a join to a derived table or CTE.

Comment: @TMcKeown Hm, I didn't see that part about the single row. If it's a single row, then we're in agreement ;) But if it's single row, it's too simple anyway. OK.

Answer (score 1):

In a STORED PROCEDURE you will need to use variables, for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NameProc(
  @s0 AS INT,
  @s1 AS INT,
  @s2 AS INT,
  @s3 AS INT,
  @s4 AS INT,
  @s5 AS INT,
  @s6 AS INT
)
AS


UPDATE myTable SET s0=ROUND(@s0/(@s0+@s1+@s2+@s3+@s4+@s5+@s6)*100)/100 
      s1=ROUND(@s1/(@s0+@s1+@s2+@s3+@s4+@s5+@s6)*100)/100 
      s2=ROUND(@s2/(@s0+@s1+@s2+@s3+@s4+@s5+@s6)*100)/100
```

Comment: did you DECLARE the variables and assign them values?

Comment: @TMcKeown I would provide a full script which works. I got interested in your solution too. Note that this has to be done for each row. Your solution seems interesting if it works OK.

Comment: Now I think your idea does not work. Do you need a cursor to loop through your rows?!

Comment: you would use my solution when using stored procedures or you can even use in c#.